# How to make javascript image blob object in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, blob

I have to make an image blob object like this :

[image]

Now I can get the image base64 url in react native which I store in a variable :

```
const base64 = img.data;
```

I've tried this way but didn't work :

```
  function b64toBlob(dataURI) {
      var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
      var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
      var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
      for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      return new Blob([ab], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
    }
    const blob = b64toBlob(base64);

    console.log(blob);
```

[image]

```
const base64 = img.data;
```

Now How can I create a blob object just like the image above with this base64 variable in react native ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue this way :

```
  ImagePicker.openPicker({
                      width: 400,
                      height: 400,
                      cropping: true,
                      includeBase64: true,
                    })
                      .then(image => {
                        setImg(image);
                      })
                      .then(() => setModalVisible(prev => !prev));


  const image = {
        name: nn,
        uri: img.path,
        type: img.mime,
        size: img.size,
        lastModifiedDate: JSON.parse(img.modificationDate),
        uid: img.modificationDate,
      };
      const form = new FormData();
      form.append('file', image);
      axios
        .post('url', form, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `bearer ${JSON.parse(token)}`,
          },
        })
```